# Pinging S3 static hosted bucket returns different IP address each time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket - **mybucket** in S3 and enabled static website hosting on it. The URL to access this bucket is http://mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. Everything works fine when I access this bucket. However, when I ping mybucket.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com, I receive response from a different IP address each time. Does that mean that the website is being hosted (and served) by a lot of (virtual) machines? Or something else is at play here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is absolutely correct. Single S3 bucked is managed and served by multiple virtual machines. These machines might be a bunch of things like load balancers, API endpoints, file servers, backup/replication servers... AWS hides all the complexity from you and provides 99.999999999% (eleven nines) durability, high availability, extremely low cost, compared to DIY EC2+EBS hosting etc.

Not being able to rely on the static IP address to access the bucket is really a small price to pay for all the work that goes on behind the scenes.